# "Review queues" button spots an "attention badge" even while you are review banned

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar, review-suspension

[image]

Possibly only during the last [your timezone - SO timezone] hours of ban, but, for obvious reasons, that's hard to verify as an end user.

Update, as I fell for an attention test with a too-short late answer again: it seems likely that this shows up when the the icon usually lights up to invite you to review because there are too many items in the review queue(s)

[image]

Comment: FWIW the UX is the same for when you've exhausted all your daily allotted review tasks or your available flags. IOW that indicator shows the review-queues overall state, it is not personalized for you, nor for anyone else. As such it is not a bug and as a feature request it probably is a duplicate.

Comment: Followed that chain of linked questions to a few years ago (with last confirmation of something being looked at in 2017), and, well, I guess I'll just userstyle this button out of existence and not touch it until the situation changes (or, "if" the situation changes). Also stumbled upon [this comment of yours](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/389434/review-queue-showing-review-alert-for-users-who-cant-review#comment728049_389434) from 3 years ago, which seems incredibly apt

Comment: This is now [tag:status-planned]: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351118/improved-experience-for-users-with-review-suspensions/351161?noredirect=1#comment1175921_351161

Comment: Sweet! Haven't really been doing reviews lately since the UI flow is clunky, but glad to read that at least something is happening.